# Missing QObject Build Dependency Qt 5.15.2

Tags: windows, qt, environment-variables, dependencies, qt5

I've been stuck on this issue for far too long. I am trying to build an application using Qt 5.15.2 and C++ compiler 16.5.29911.84 (x86_amd64) on Windows 10. However no matter what I try I seem to get the same error: `Dependent '..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\QObject does not exist`

I've tried the following:

- Checking to see if QObject exists at the specified path (it does)
- Changing the INCLUDEPATH in my .pro file to include "C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore" which is where QObject lives
- Confirmed that my header file defines QTObject as: #include
- Verified my .pro file has the QT Flag: QT += core
- Defined Environment Variable on my Windows machine as QTDir = C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64 and added %ATDIR%\bin to my PATH variable
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Qt

After each of these changes I clean the project, run qmake and then build the project. However, each time the build fails with the original error.

Any suggestions of how to fix the problem or narrow down the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Update:
I've narrowed down the problem to an incorrect filepath in the makefiles. If I change the path from `..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.15.2\*` to `C:\Qt\5.15.2\*` the application builds.
Where do I specify this path in Qt such that it uses the absolute path and not the relative path?

Comment: The error message has the path as `msvc2019_64\QtCore`... instead of `msvc2019_64\include\QtCore`...  Is this a copy-paste error or does the error message have the wrong path?

Comment: It was a copy and paste error. I've updated @RA.

Comment: Does adding `QMAKE_PROJECT_DEPTH = 0` to your `.pro` file make a difference?